# rails select in activerecord I can not understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i do select: "SELECT date, triggerid, severity, status, types.name, recipient FROM logs, types WHERE logs.type_id = types.id;"?
 I have talble logs where column "type_id" contains(1,2,2,3,3,1...), i need do sql select to be:(email,sms,sms,voice,voice,email...) where table "types" conains id(1,2,3), name(email,sms,voice)

migrations:

```
   create_table :logs, id: false do |t|
  t.integer         :date,          unsigned: true
  t.integer         :triggerid,     unsigned: true
  t.integer         :severity,      unsigned: true
  t.integer         :status,        unsigned: true
  t.integer         :type_id,       unsigned: true
  t.string          :recipient,     limit: 100

   create_table :types do |t|
  t.string      :name,      limit: 7
end
```

Comment: I think this migration definition is invalid ruby.

Comment: what should be the migration for get result?

Comment: What result would that be?

Comment: types.name contains: (email, sms, voice), types.id:(1,2,3), logs.type_id: (1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2). result should be: (email, email, email, voice,voice....)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Migrations:**

1.1. LogsTable

```
    class CreateLogs < ActiveRecord::Migration

      def change
        create_table   :logs do |t|
          t.integer         :date,          unsigned: true
          t.integer         :triggerid,     unsigned: true
          t.integer         :severity,      unsigned: true
          t.integer         :status,        unsigned: true
          t.integer         :type_id,       unsigned: true
          t.string          :recipient,     limit: 100
          t.references      :type
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
   end
```

TypesTable:

```
class CreateTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table   :types do |t|
      t.string      :name,      limit: 7

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

1.3. `rake db:migrate`

**2. Models:**

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type 
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logs #or has_one, I don't know your app logic
end
```

Now you can select instance of the log by it's "type_id".

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, what should be query to select column "references :type"?

Comment: It would be nice if you'll edit/update your question with description of the logic of your app you want to implement (in English, not in SQL), because, speaking frankly, I don't get it.

Comment: Unfortunately my English is worse than sql), geyerally i have talble logs where column "type_id" contains(1,2,2,3,3,1...), ineed to be:(email,sms,sms,voice,voice,email...) where table "types" conains id(1,2,3), name(email,sms,voice)

Comment: What are this "email", "sms", "voice"? They are attributes of what? I can't see the definition of them in your question. Maybe you have link to git repo with your app?